# How to not call the helper function recursively in the min-thirty-percent function?

Tags: racket

```
(define (sum lst finalans)
  (cond
    [(empty? lst) finalans]
    [else (+ finalans (first lst) (sum (rest lst) finalans))]))


(define (min-thirty-percent lst)
  (cond
    [(empty? lst) empty]
    [(> (first lst) (* 0.3 (sum lst 0))) (cons (first lst) (min-thirty-percent (rest lst)))]
    [else (min-thirty-percent (rest lst))]))
```

I have written this program and I don't want to calculate the sum recursively. The sum value changes as the list changes, but I don't want that. I want the sum of the list to be calculated once and then be compared.
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd like to point out that in your example, `finalans` is *always* 0. It looks like you're trying to use an accumulator there, but you're just calling it directly. I suggest you remove it altogether giving you:

```
(define (sum lst)
  (cond
    [(empty? lst) 0]
    [else (+ (first lst) (sum (rest lst)))]))
```

Or, you could simplify it by just using [`sum` provided by `math/base`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/math/base.html?q=sum#%28def._%28%28lib._math%2Fbase..rkt%29._sum%29%29)

Now, what you probably want is an additional pseudo-helper function for `min-thirty-percent`, that allows you to calculate the sum once, and then make your recursive calls from there. It turns out Racket's named `let` syntax is very convenient for this:

```
(define (min-thirty-percent lst)
  (let loop ([lst lst]
             [min30 (* 0.3 (sum lst))])
    (cond
      [(empty? lst) empty]
      [(> (first lst) min30) (cons (first lst) (loop (rest lst) min30))]
      [else (loop (rest lst) min30)]))
```

Although, because this is such a simple operation, you can also just use racket's `for/list` construct directly, and skip recursion altogether:

```
(define (min-thirty-percent lst)
  (define min30 (sum lst)
  (for/list ([i lst]
             #:when (i . > . min30))
    i))
```